# Wiremock variable substitution in JSON response

Tags: json, jsonpath, wiremock

I am trying to configure Wiremock mappings to return a JSON response with a value from the request.

The request is simply

```
{ "clientTag": "123" }
```

And the mapping for it is:

```
{
  "priority": 4,
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/test"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{ \"loginId\": \"${loginId}\" }",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  },
  "captures" : [ {
            "source" : "BODY",
            "target" : "loginId",
            "pattern" : "$..clientTag",
            "captureGroup" : 1
  } ]
}
```

I receive the response:

```
{ "loginId": "" }
```

while the expected one is:

```
{ "loginId": "123" }
```

If I switch to XML requests, everything works fine with the pattern `<clientTag>(.*?)</clientTag>`, but I would like to stick to JSON.

Unfortunately Wiremock documentation is scarce hence the question. Any ideas?

UPDATE: If someone is reading this later, you'd do best to use the transforms in the code, which are available in the later Wiremock versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use-case for [OpenTable's Wiremock Body Transformer](https://github.com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer).

It can be easily integrated with the Standalone Server like this:

`java -cp "wiremock-body-transformer-1.1.6.jar:wiremock-2.3.1-standalone.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --verbose --extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer`

This extension allows you to easily specify a variable in the request that you would want to match in the response.

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/transform",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "$.name"
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "{\"responseName\": \"$(name)\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["body-transformer"]
    }
}
```

It also easily allows you to generate a random integer in the response as seen here:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/transform",
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "{\"randomInteger\": \"$(!RandomInteger)\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformers": ["body-transformer"]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it in the end, thanks! My bad not updating the question.

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 3):

[WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) does support this now.

When sending a **request** like:

```
{
    "username": "stef"
}
```

And using **mapping** like:

```
{
  "Request": {
    "Path": {
      "Matchers": [
        {
          "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
          "Pattern": "/test"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Methods": [
      "post"
    ]
  },
  "Response": {
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "BodyAsJson": {
      "path": "{{request.path}}",
      "result": "{{JsonPath.SelectToken request.bodyAsJson \"username\"}}"
    },
    "UseTransformer": true,
    "Headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

The **response** will be like:

```
{
    "path": "/test",
    "result": "stef"
}
```

Note that this functionality is currently in preview mode, see NuGet package version 1.0.4.8-preview-01.

If you have any questions, just create an issue on this github project.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've added an extension you haven't mentioned, this can't work - there's no "captures" element in the JSON API, and no way (without extensions) to do variable substitution in responses.

Comment: Hi Tom, firstly, thanks for the excellent mock! You are right, I checked and found out that we really have extensions for the capture, I'll dig from that.

Is there a complete JSON API for wiremock? I struggle to find much information about it over the Internet.

Comment: There isn't a single doc covering the entire JSON API, but it's all covered throughout wiremock.org. Is there something specific you're looking for?