# WireMock - How to Include Request JSON Body Into the Response Body?

Tags: junit, spring-boot-test, wiremock, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

### What I have achieved so far?

I'm using WireMock with Spring Boot Application using the JUNIT 5.

I am stubbing the `test` endpoint with the custom Request and Response JSON payload:

REQUEST PAYLOAD:

```json
{
    "merchantId": "xxxx",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "unique-id-1",
            "sensitiveData": "xxxxxx",
        },
      ...
      ...
   ]
}
```

RESPONSE PAYLOAD:

```json
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "id": "unique-id-1",
            "token": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        },
           ...
           ...  

   ]
}
```

### What I'm trying to achieve?

Since my JSON Request payload is dynamic. I want to create a dynamic JSON Payload in response as well where tokens values in JSON are static but the id's value in JSON is dynamic based on the request payload's id value.

```java
@SpringBatchTest
class FileTest{
   private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

   BeforeEach
   void setUp() {
       wireMockServer =
         new WireMockServer(options().extensions(new          
             ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)).port(PORT));

       WireMock.configureFor("localhost", PORT);
       wireMockServer.start();
  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
       wireMockServer.stop();
  

@Test
  void testEndToEndFlowForSpringBatch() {
       final String body = ResponsePayload.getResponseJsonPayload();
       wireMockServer.addStubMapping(
        stubFor(
            post(urlPathMatching("/test"))
                .willReturn(
                    aResponse()
                        .withBody(body)
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withTransformers("response-template"))));
       //morecode
}
```

###### ResponsePayload.getResponseJsonPayload() contains below value:

```json
{
    "response": "SUCCESS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "id": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.data[0].id'}}",
            "token": "xxxxxx",
        },
        {
            "id": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.data[1].id'}}",
            "token": "xxxxxxx",
        },
                  ..
    ]
}
```

### What is not working?

When I am debugging the program I can see the stub is throwing following error:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /test. Reason:
<pre>    wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@1e0c0274:5:21: could not find helper: &apos;jsonPath&apos;
            &quot;id&quot;: &quot;{{jsonPath request.body &apos;$.merchantId&apos;}}&quot;,
                     ^
</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already read below answers but couldn't find a way of using the `jsonPath`:

- [Wiremock variable substitution in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289085/wiremock-variable-substitution-in-json-response)
- [WireMock: How configure a JSON to show request headers in the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035502/wiremock-how-configure-a-json-to-show-request-headers-in-the-response)
- [WireMock post stub with request body and response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73414389/wiremock-post-stub-with-request-body-and-response-body)

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to fix the issue was to upgrade the version of WireMock from `<version>2.6.0</version>` to the latest one `<version>3.0.0-beta-9</version>`.

Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-beta-9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can get the latest one from the Maven store here: [Maven Store](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone)

Also, create the server this way:

```java
private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    wireMockServer =
        new WireMockServer(
                options()
                .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true))
                .port(PORT));

    wireMockServer.start();
}
```

And in the stub:

```java
@Test
void testWireMockServerIsUp() {
    wireMockServer.stubFor(
        post(urlPathMatching("/test"))
            .willReturn(
                aResponse().withBody(body).withStatus(200)));
}
```

Comment: https://wiremock.org/3.x/docs/response-templating/#enabling-response-templating -> You shouldn't ned to include the `.withTransformers("response-template")` if you have `ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)`.

Comment: @agoff thanks for the catch! Modifying my answer.